# MySQL: how to join four tables (Active Record syntax)

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, join, normalization

For a particular material in my materials table with an ID of 20, I have two tables:

```
chemical_name_id | chemical_name  (table name: ml_chemical_names)
================================
1                | Polysomething

common_name_id | common_name (table name: ml_common_names)
=============================
1              | PMMA
2              | Lucite
3              | Perspex
4              | Plexiglas

material_id | material  (table name: ml_materials)
======================
20          | Acrylic
```

I'm a little green at joining these tables, but I created two lookup tables, like this:

```
material_id | common_name_id (table name: ml_materials_common_names)
============================
20           | 1
20           | 2
20           | 3
20           | 4

and

material_id | chemical_name (table name: ml_materials_chemical_names)
===========================
20          | 1
```

Here is my SQL in Active Record (CodeIgniter) format:

```
$this->db->like('cn.common_name', $options['keyword']);
$this->db->or_like('chem.chemical_name', $options['keyword']);
$this->db->join('ml_materials_chemical_names mchem', 'mchem.material_id = m.material_id', 'inner');
$this->db->join('ml_chemical_names chem', 'chem.chemical_name_id = mchem.chemical_name_id', 'inner');
$this->db->join('ml_materials_common_names mcn', 'mcn.material_id = m.material_id', 'inner');
$this->db->join('ml_common_names cn', 'cn.common_name_id = mcn.common_name_id', 'inner');
return $this->db->get('ml_materials m')->result();
```

This is used in an AJAX search form.  Thing is, when the search is for "polysomething" I get four results.  I only want one.  I'm not sure if it's my tables that are stuctured wrong or my joins.  I've tried left, right and outer joins and nothing seems to change in terms of the results returned.

Can someone help?

Comment: what is your expected result? your ml_materials_common_names has four rows for material_id 20, so it will return 4 rows.

Comment: have you tried using last query to see just what codeigniter is actually doing as a query?  I would suspect that it has to do with unspecified aliasing of material_id as a guess

Comment: rs--I would expect four rows, but I want to resturcture this so I only get one row

Comment: john b-- What do you mean by unspecified aliasing?  What do I need to do?

Comment: which one of the four do you want?  if it doesn't matter you could just use a limit clause.  if it does then which one do you want?

Comment: The four seem to be identical.  I assume it's because there are four common names.  I can't use a limit clause because this has to be flexible enough to search for the data and return multiple results that are returned as users input each character that is typed in the search box.  Results for 'po'  Results for 'pol'  Results for 'pol'  etc.

Comment: I'll try distinct.  Thanks, rs.

Comment: @rs, your last comment should be an answer and shummel7845 should accept it if it is working.